# node-rsa and openssl compatibility

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, node-rsa

I have a set of public/private keys, that works flawless when encrypting/decrypting some data using only one of the 2 ways for both encryption and decryption.

I still have no luck trying to encrypt the data with the one of the two and decrypt it with the other.

Example schenario:

a) I create some encrypted data using the public key with the following node.js code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
var fs = require('fs');

function createUsingPubKey(Pub, data) {
    var pk = new NodeRSA();
    pk.importKey(Pub);
    encrypted = pk.encrypt(data, 'base64');
    return encrypted;
}

var sampledata = "SECRET STUFF";

var genkey = createUsingPubKey(fs.readFileSync('id_rsa.pub'), sampledata)
console.log(genkey);
```

b) Then i try to decrypt it using openssl utility with this:

```
node test.js | openssl base64 -d -A | openssl rsautl -inkey id_rsa
```

But i get:

```
RSA operation error
1068:error:0406706C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:680:
```

I thought that they probably would use different algorithms for the encryption/decryption procedure so i headed to the node-rsa documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa and i found this option:

> encryptionScheme — padding scheme for encrypt/decrypt. Can be
>   'pkcs1_oaep' or 'pkcs1'. Default 'pkcs1_oaep'.

I then tried to decrypt passing the -oaep option in openssl util like this:

```
node test.js | openssl base64 -d -A | openssl rsautl -oaep -inkey id_rsa
```

But i still get:

```
RSA operation error
5216:error:0406706C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:680:
```

My knowledge on cryptography is really basic. Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT 1:
The node.js module can be found here:
https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa

EDIT 2:
As Maarten Bodewes requested, here is some sample data:

Plaintext data to be encrypted:

> You're no good, you're no good, you're no good Baby, you're no good
>   (I'm gonna say it again) You're no good, you're no good, you're no
>   good Baby, you're no good

A private key generated with

```
openssl genrsa -out key 512

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBALOUBygyX11BsDoEIKoZzn2/HAXPorNR/X8wCDaBlcPtOHxKAZFk
Vra1+Pem1urtSlnEqc07DwAP6v0GEGHpxbkCAwEAAQJAGAZ17qrOl2tyaFClDhzl
w20OErj0y4jsoVeLwb8UimG48JslS14hfM9XxE/fG6qypN8u7LUhlnBC68ZcQ9Jg
AQIhAORaVlB7trWp6n7dETvdY9J2p8ubOuyLTX0BA2jF8agxAiEAyVHzDWQPWx/s
gt+ABErqN+ZUWS016DD34QUVGyp9nAkCIQC39JpSDcd7gx1YA8jNXCT9N/8mg6+t
PO84g2d2sPdjEQIgXwWMF/TzfopJ4tfFH8GQXYQcqd66A/cg+Jeih6j9kqkCIGD4
hBAO0haqnqeSO65Mm1IjY/6Z77pKxzJAGys5XeXk
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And its equivalent pub key

```
openssl rsa -in key -pubout > key.pub

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALOUBygyX11BsDoEIKoZzn2/HAXPorNR
/X8wCDaBlcPtOHxKAZFkVra1+Pem1urtSlnEqc07DwAP6v0GEGHpxbkCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The above plaintext data encrypted with the given public key using the node.js rsa library:

```
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
```

Comment: id_rsa.pub is your ssh public key, right? So it isn't PEM encoded.

Comment: no i use a pem encoded public key

Comment: What's the output of `node test.js | openssl base64 -d -A`? Could you provide output of `node test.js`?  In that case it is easy to find out ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add -decrypt argument for openssl

```
node test.js | openssl base64 -d -A | openssl rsautl -decrypt -oaep -inkey id_rsa
```

works pretty nice for me.

Comment: Your data should be less than key size in bytes minus some bytes for padding. You can see max data length (in bytes) for key-padding pair in NodeRSA by .getMaxMessageSize() method. 
If data size in bytes greater than this number NodeRSA devide data to smaller pieces and make several encrypt rounds, then concatenate results. But it not defined in RSA spec, if you want using openssl with NodeRSA you should pay attention for your data size.

Comment: Fantastic! So to decrypt my data that were encoded using node-rsa i have to spit them in chucks of <= .getMaxMessageSize(), decrypt every chunk and then concatenate them back again?

Comment: Yes, f.e. you initial data size 120 bytes, and result of .getMaxMessageSize() == 50 bytes, it means nodersa will divide your data to 3 piece, encrypt each and concatenate results. Result size will be 3*key_size. So, if you want decrypt it, you should divide encrypted data for 3 equal chunks (each chunk will be equal of your key lenght in bytes), decrypt one by one and concatenate results. OR better — don't encrypt data larger than .getMaxMessageSize().

Comment: Lol, the `RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT` routine was probably called because of the private key, but it may have struggled with the padded message :)

Comment: Have you managed to use node-rssa to decrypt data encrypted with openssl? Could you share the code? Thanks,